# What can I do with "Mientras"?

Tags: verbos

I understand that I can never join two Preterite verbs with `Mientras`, since it implies an ongoing action, but what can I do with `mientras`?

Is it acceptable to have a Preterite and Imperfect verb joined by `Mientras`? Also, are there any restrictions with `Cuando` or can I join any past tense verbs with it.

Thanks

Comment: I think it's not right what you say, but it would be good to you to give us any examples to give you a clear answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes

it is perfectly acceptable to use mientras with both preterite and imperfect.
With `mientras` you can have either two imperfect conjugations or one with a preterite.

> Mientras me estaba duchando mi hermanito subió la temperatura.
>
> Yo gané mucho dinero mientras tú echabas la hueva
>
> Yo comí mientras tú bebías.

With both

> Nosotros nos bajábamos del ascensor mientras ellas se subían.
>
> Los dinosaurios se ponían nerviosos mientras explotaba el sol.
>
> Yo lloraba mientras mi hermanito me quemaba *al subir la temperatura del agua.*

Comment: The last example is quite disturbing...

Comment: is that better?

Comment: Quizá *al subir la temperatura...*

Comment: You should make clear that one of the verbs has to be in imperfect form, you can't join to perfect preterites with *mientras*.

Comment: The OP already mentioned that he/she was aware of that aleady.

Answer (score 0):

Just as with most grammar rules, there are exceptions to the rule that you cannot have two verbs conjugated in preterit with `mientras`. Here's an example:

> Mientras estuvo enfermo no le faltaron visitas.
>
> (While he was sick he had plenty of visitors.)

The example is from the book "El subjuntivo en español" by María Ángeles Sastre Ruano (Ediciones Colegio de España, 1997). Page 154.